# My WPF listview will not bind

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

This may seem an odd question but I am stuck.

I am using ListViews in my wpf app that dynamically binds to list collections.

Apart from one. I just cannot see what is wrong/different.

This is my model:

```
public class WorkUnitCost
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int WorkUnitCostId { get; set; }
    public bool IsUploaded { get; set; }
    public string WorkUnitCostRef { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public bool IncludesVAT { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRef { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Exists { get; set; }
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return Description + " £" + Cost; }
    }
}
```

This is my collection:

```
public List<WorkUnitCost> WorkUnitCost = new List<Model.WorkUnitCost>();
```

This is my code-behind:

```
lvWorkItems.ItemsSource = WorkUnitCost;
```

This is my markup:

```
     <ListView x:Name="lvWorkItems">           
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="190" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="IsVat" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IncludesVAT}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Cost" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cost}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

By setting a break-point I know there are 2 items with populated fields. Yet, nothing is visually displayed?

Comment: Maybe because you don't use ObservableCollection? I suppose your ListView doesn't know about added items.

Comment: had not realized that. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are adding items to your colleciton after setting it as `ItemsSource`, your UI won't get notified about changes.

You will have to use some collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` instead. `ObservableCollection<T>` is most common choice.

Comment: Thanks @Spawn said the same.  All educational. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement The `INotifyCollectionChanged`  to your model 
and instead of `List` try to use `ObservableCollection<WorkUnitCost>`to enable your view synchronize with your model data. Actually It will be better if you use `MVVM` to ensure the best practices for `WPF`, you will find at this [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-18-Understanding-MVVM-ObservableCollection-T-and-INotifyPropertyChanged) a good explanation of how to use `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` with `MVVM` design pattern